# Podtemplate() not accepting the yaml file using readFile or yamlFile

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, readfile

my code:

```
podTemplate(label: slave_label, cloud: ${cloud_name}, readFile : 'deploy.yml') {

}
```

I used yamlFile and readFile also its not taking the inputs. bddrunner pod is not starting

When I use this direct yaml method its working fine. like this:

```
podTemplate(label: slave_label, cloud: ${cloud_name}, yaml: """ """) {
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates
`yaml: readFile('path-to-file')`

It must be noted that readFile only works inside an active workspace. That means you have to be in a Node section.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

Your code should be:

```
podTemplate(label: slave_label, cloud: ${cloud_name}, yaml: readFile('deploy.yml')) {

}
```

edit: Corrected brain typo from `yamlFile:` to `yaml:`.
`yamlFile` should not be used in the Jenkins Scripted Pipeline.

Comment: you don't need `readFile` with `yamlFile`, but `yamlFile` is only supported in declarative pipeline. The example is good, but the first line should be `yaml: readFile('path-to-file')`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this week and was not able to find fast the proper solution.

According to the plugin documentation (https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pod-and-container-template-configuration) to load an yaml file you should use `readFile` or `readTrusted`. This is wrong for the scripted pipelines, because these commands can be used when you already have the agent pod only (so "you cannot bite your own tail").

The solution I found is to place all your yamls like `maven-build-release.yaml` in the `resources/` folder and load the needed configuration with help of `libraryResource` like this:

```
[...]
podTemplate(
  yaml: libraryResource('maven-build-release.yaml')) {
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Clone Source Code (Git)') {
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

The option is `yamlFile` not `readFile`
See this example https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/examples/declarative_from_yaml_file/Jenkinsfile

Comment: `yamlFile` is only supported in declarative pipeline. For scripted you need `yaml: readFile('thefile')`